# Popup not opening on button click chrome headless on linux

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

I am automating one test case where I clicks on Add key button on bit bucket and open popup as per below screenshot :

[image]

Somehow this popup is not opening when I run my script using jenkins on linux AWS.

I am using Selenium Webdriver , Java, Chrome Headless and maven.

Here is my settings in code for chrome headless :

```
          HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            chromePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + prop.getProperty("chromeDriverPath");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
            options.addArguments("--always-authorize-plugins");
            options.addArguments("enable-automation");
            options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Am I missing any other argument which can help me to resolve this issue?

Html Code of button where clicked and open popup :

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="aui-button aui-button-primary" id="add-key" resolved="">Add key</button>

  </div>
```

Screenshot of Html :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Add key** you can use the following solution:

- It seems that that some of the elements are dynamically generated, ideally instead of `PageLoadStrategy.NONE` you need to use **`PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL`** as follows:

  ```
  options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
  ```
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  - `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.aui-button.aui-button-primary#add-key"))).click();
    ```
  - `XPATH`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='aui-button aui-button-primary' and @id='add-key'][text()='Add key']"))).click();
    ```